# how to read runtime annotations on a field within a class

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

Imagine an annotation called "MyAnn" with runtime retention, a class MyClass, and an abstract class called MyData. MyClass has a field of type MyData, annotated with MyAnn. Within the instance of MyData, how do see if the annotation MyAnn is present and retrieve its information?

Note - in Java8 I know we can directly annotate the inner class at construction - and that works - but I need this working based on the field annotation.

Thanks for any help!

```
public MyClass extends MySuperClass() {
   @MyAnn(value = "something")
   protected MyData mydata;

   public void doSomething() {
      mydata = new MyData() {};
      mydata.initialize();
   }
}

public abstract MyData() {
   String myValue = null;

   public void initialize() {
      if (***I am annotated with MyAnn) {
         myValue = (***value from annotation MyAnn);         
      }
   }
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnn {
    String myvalue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyData` cannot directly know whether it has been annotated with `MyAnn`, because it has no knowledge of whether the current instance is a field or a standalone instance, and if it is a field, then whether the field has or has not been annotated with `MyAnn`.

So, you will need to somehow obtain and pass the `value` to `initialize()`, and you will need to somehow obtain the `value` at the place where `initialize()` is called.  And from your code, it appears that `"something"` can be passed as a parameter to `initialize()`, making the whole thing a lot easier than annotating the field and then checking whether the field is annotated.

But in any case, if you want to check whether a field is annotated, you have to:

- obtain the fields of your class with `getClass().getDeclaredFields()`
- loop over the fields; for each field, either

  - invoke `isAnnotationPresent( MyAnn.class )` or
  - invoke `field.getAnnotations()`, loop for each annotation, and check whether this `annotation instanceof MyAnn.class`

Once you have found the annotation, you can get its value with `annotation.value();`

Comment: Note that an *instance* of `MyData` needs details on a *field* of `MyData`. With the approach provided here it is necessary to know the class that declares the respective field at compile time.

Comment: @Izruo I did not understand your comment, but in any case, it made me rethink my answer, so I amended it.

Comment: I believe what @lzruo is pointing out, is that for the instance "mydata" to be able to introspect its parent class using the technique you describe (iterating over the fields and checking the annotations), it needs a way to "identify" itself, e.g. how to know when it reaches the field "mydata" in the parent class, that this is its own declaration. I can't think of an easy way to do this...